# SingleChildScrollView reset when using setState to update ShaderMask

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add a blur effect to a SingleChildScrollView to indicate that there is content to be scrolled, which should disappear when the scrollable is fully scrolled.

So far I have got this:

```
    ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100),
      child: StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setState) {
          return ShaderMask(
            shaderCallback: (Rect rect) {
              return LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [
                  Colors.white,
                  shouldBlur ? Colors.white.withOpacity(0.05) : Colors.white
                ],
                stops: const [0.7, 1],
                tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
              ).createShader(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height));
            },
            blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _scrollController,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: _buildGroupsTable(filteredList),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
```

where my variables are defined as:

```
      late ScrollController _scrollController;
      bool shouldBlur = true;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _scrollController = ScrollController(
          onAttach: _handlePositionAttach,
        );
      }
    
      void _handleScrollChange() {
        if (_scrollController.position.extentAfter > 0 != shouldBlur) {
          setState(() {
            shouldBlur = !shouldBlur;
          });
        }
      }
    
      void _handlePositionAttach(ScrollPosition position) {
        position.isScrollingNotifier.addListener(_handleScrollChange);
      }
```

What ends up happening is that when the setState is called, the whole widget is rebuilt, and the scroll is reset.

I tried adding a global key to the SingleChildScrollView, but it didn't change anything.

How can I make this work? Or is there a better way to achieve this behaviour?